# With Cmder as a bash console where to declare a function to call with arguments, like an alias

Tags: bash, function, alias, cmder

I use Cmder, I declared bash aliases in `Cmder\config\user_profile.sh` and I can use them in bash console mode. But in the same file declared functions don't work in bash console mode.

```
function hello {
    echo "Hello $1 !"
}
```

Wrong file, wrong syntax, not possible ???

Comment: In file `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the pb !
We need to respect the syntax like this :

```
function hello {
    echo "Hello $1 !"
}
```

and never like this :

```
function hello { echo "Hello $1 !" }
```

because of a problem of unexpected end file.
Indeed we are not under Windows shell ! o:)

UPDATE : functional syntax on one line

```
hello() { echo "Hello $1 !"; }
```

Comment: The standard syntax for defining a shell function doesn't use the `function` keyword, just `()`. Also, you can define it in a single line, but you need a `;` after the `echo` command, so the `}` isn't mistaken for just another argument to `echo`. So use `hello() { echo "Hello $1 !"; }`